# other parts of the mesh are being pulled when posing

Tags: modeling, mesh

Been trying to rig this model up but other parts are being pulled when posing

followed a couple tutorials and even got rigify pro

do you think its my model that is the problem?

Here's the .blend, for reference:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NCKCOJiapLdd4PcchW2YoAuSCxRJFwLf/view?usp=sharing

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: That link requests access so we can't download your file. Please share it through the official site at https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link and then edit and paste it into your question.

Comment: cheers, updated the link now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following things:

- Unparent the object with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Clear and Keep Transformations*
- Apply the scale of the character mesh with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>
- In *Edit* mode select all, <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* in order to remove overlapping vertices, and <kbd>Shit</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> recalculate the normals. Back to *Object* mode, richt click > *Shade Smooth*
- Deactivate the *Deform* option of the root and target bones
- Parent again *With Automatic Weights*